# In Blender, how do I programmatically display a viewport rendering in a window just like if you pressed F12?

Tags: rendering, opengl

I  know I can call `bpy.ops.render.opengl()` and that will create the render, but what I want to do is to create and then view the render, just like what happens when you use the **View > Viewport Render Image** menu item. Is there a way to do this?

So, to ask another way, how can I call the render window (F11) via python? F11 Hides or shows the render window.

Comment: I thought it was `bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True)` for an actual render and  `bpy.ops.render.opengl()` for viewport render.

Comment: Yes, both *create* a render, but they don't show the render in a new window, like the F12 button does.

Comment: Yeah, that's a little deeper than I'm comfortable advising on, given my limited experience with blender python. Do you need to call on the window manager? I'll upvote the question and hopefully send it into someone else's more capable hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invoke the operator.**

When called from the UI an operator is "invoked" with "default" settings. To do same from script `bpy.ops.foo.bar('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`

[What do different execution contexts mean?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50249/what-do-different-execution-contexts-mean)

From python console,

```
>>> bpy.ops.render.opengl('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

does the "UI thing" and opens the render window (if that's your setting)

whereas

```
>>> bpy.ops.render.opengl()
{'FINISHED'}
```

executes the operator.

Comment: While that works, all code beneath that (where I reset the viewport props) is executed *before* the render. Whereas if I don't use INVOKE_DEFAULT, the code is executed in the correct order. Can I use a timer or something to make sure the code is executed *after*?